# Display all products in single url

Tags: magento2.4.5

We want to display all the products information in single frontend url.

So I followed [link](https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/does-magento-2-have-a-default-url-to-display-all-products.html) and done below configuration. but i did't got from which url , we can able to get all the product's information? I have only backend access.

**Step 1**. Navigate to Stores > Settings > Configuration.

**Step 2**. Open the Catalog settings and select the Catalog under it.

**Step 3**. Open the Storefront settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It will display 'All' in pager on all category pages. Then go to your root category (it usually has 'default-category' url) and select 'All' from a 'Show' dropdown.

Comment: i recently joined the project, there are no products in root main category : https://prnt.sc/u5XNYy5p8Mk-